# Arg type 'String? Function(String)' & 'void? Function(String)' can't assigned to param type String? Function(String?)? and void? Function(String?)?

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, email-validation, dart-null-safety

I am getting argument type not assignable error in dart while checking the email value is empty or not the error which I am getting are

> The argument type `void Function(String)` can't be assigned to the parameter type `void Function(String?)?`.

and

> The argument type `String? Function(String)` can't be assigned to the parameter type `'String? Function(String?)?`.

These are the validator classes,

```
class EmailFieldValidator {
static String? validate(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty' : null;
  }

}

class PasswordFieldValidator {
  static String? validate(String value) {
    return value.isEmpty ? 'Password can\'t be empty' : null;
  }
}
```

Here is the code giving the error

```
 List<Widget> buildInputs() {
    return <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        key: Key('email'),
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
        validator: EmailFieldValidator.validate, //this gives string error mentioned above
        onSaved: (String value) => _email = value, //getting void error mention above 
      ),
      TextFormField(
        key: Key('password'),
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
        obscureText: true,
        validator: PasswordFieldValidator.validate,  // getting string error mentioned above
        onSaved: (String value) => _password = value, //getting void error mention above 
      ),
    ];
  }
```

Comment: What do you understand of those error messages?

Comment: I guess the error message says that it isnt allowing to assign a non-nullable value to nullable type and I tried to make suitable changes but that didnt worked out like adding null check(!)

Comment: The null check isn't the issue. It's the types of the `XFieldValidator.validate` functions themselves. Nothing you do within those functions is relevant to the error, the issue is that their types are incorrect. As the error suggests, the type expected by `TextFormField` for its validator is `String? Function(String?)`, so you need to declare it with a function signature of `String? validate(String? value)`.

Comment: thanks a ton @Alexander, I gotcha and solved the error for both

Comment: I've formalized my comment into a more fleshed-out answer. Hopefully I've helped you built some understanding on what these errors mean, and the fix from there should be straight forward. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem faced after the Null Safety thing came to flutter. I just normally cast it as a String to use it. Sometimes it gives out errors but not errors which will potentially break your app.

```
onSaved: (String? value) => _email = value as String,


static String? validate(String? value) {
String valueString = value as String;
// Do Your Usual thing over here like checking if it's empty}
```

Comment: thanks @kushalagrwal 
Alexander just explained me what silly error I made 
Thanks for your contribution

Comment: This force cast completely defeats the purpose of null safety.

Comment: @Alexander so is it better to use null safe var or force casting?

Comment: Yes I know therefore I did mention that it's just a temporary fix. And therefore it gives out errors too at points. But yes good point.

Comment: @Mithson Well let me ask you this: why do you think the Flutter API was designed such that `onSaved` takes a function with an optional `String` parameter. Why didn't they just accept a function with a non-optional `String` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

## First error

Both `EmailFieldValidator.validate` and `PasswordFieldValidator.validate` have the same type: `String? Function(String)`. That is to say, they're both functions that take a non-optional `String` as a parameter, and return a optional `String`.

The error message is telling you that the `validator` parameter to `TextFormField` is expecting a function with the type `String? Function(String?)?`. That is to say, a optional function (that is, you can pass `null` if you don't need any validator functionality at all), which itself accepts a optional `String` parameter, and returns a optional `String`.

Notice the difference: The parameters of your validator functions are not optional, but they're required to be optional. Thus, you'll need to change their function signatures:

```
static String? validate(String? /* ⬅️ Notice this is now optional! */ value) { ... }
```

Though one might ask: why not just use a lambda here, and have the types be inferred?

## Second error

The error is similar. Looking at the [docs of `TextFormField`'s constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html), we see that the type of the `onSaved` parameter is `FormFieldSetter<String>`, where [`FormFieldSetter` is just a `typealias`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormFieldSetter.html) for `void Function(T? newValue)`. Thus, the resolved type of the `onSaved` parameter is `void Function(String? newValue)`.

The lambda function you passed, `(String value) => _password = value`, takes a non-optional `String` parameter. Notice the mismatch. It needs to accept an optional, because the saving process might yield a `null` value, and you'll need to handle that.

How exactly you handle that `null` is up to you, and depends on your requirements. You might want to end up saving the `null` in your database (for example) if the field isn't mandatory. Or you might substitute a default value (though that doesn't make sense in this context). Or you in the extreme case, if you're absolutely sure you'll never ever get a null, you could force unwrap it. Of course, doing is as if you're saying the following to Dart:

> I'm super-duper sure this will never be `null`. If it is, the sky is falling, and I haven't devised a way to deal with that yet. Things are clearly not working the way I expected. Rather than carrying on forward in this misbehaved state, please just crash my app and prevent further damage

Whether that's desirable or not, depends on your problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you might return a null value whil it does not let you to use null there.

Try to add `!` after `value`:

```
onSaved: (String value) => _email = value!, 
onSaved: (String value) => _password = value!,
```

Comment: I tried adding null check but it throws ```The '!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null.
Try removing the '!' operator.```